# Why Get-Service with argument means filter by name

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am trying to understand the mechanism behind powershell comand.
I see that [get-service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176858.aspx)  return a service object that name is one of its fields, so you can filter by name (using where, select...).

I am trying to understand why when i run this:

```
Get-Service *sql*
```

PowerShell assume that the argument is filter by name? Where can i see it in the command description?

PowerShell-3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Get-Help Get-Service
```

You'll notice that the default parameter set will accept the first argument as the -Name parameter.

You are effectively doing this:

```
Get-Service -Name *sql*
```